# Notepad++ Auto-Completion Function parameters hint on input doesn't trigger on standard library function with a namespace

Tags: lua, notepad++, text-editor

Parameter hints work for functions without a namespace (i.e. `collectgarbage` or `select`). But fails to show when a "." is present in the function name (i.e. `math.cos` or `table.insert`). All of these functions are described in "Notepad++/autoCompletion/lua.xml", lua.xml has `additionalWordChar=".:"` defined and Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion has *Function parameters hint on input* and *Enable auto-completion on each input* checked.

Autocomplete does work for the functions, as in, in auto-completes them, just the parameters hints are not working as described above.

Tested on a fresh install of Notepad++ 7.8.5 release on Windows 10 64bit.

Does anyone have a fix for this? I'd like to implement function hints for custom functions and I want to piggyback off this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/) says:

> The basic character set used to recognize keywords is made of letters
>   a-z, A-Z, digits 0-9, and the underscore _. Punctuation might work for
>   auto-completion; however, if you want to use the parameter hints, you
>   should not use punctuation in the keyword name.

Maybe there is a plugin that does what you need

Comment: Well, looks like I failed to read that sentence, my bad. As for my endgoal, I abandoned Notepad++ and switched to Visual Studio Code with Lua-Language-Server as it implements most of my needs.